# Split string on number and = sign

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this string

```
6993=!ELP|6920=MP|6921=1|6922=MXGB0TC|6970=5|6926=F|6974=P
```

Looking for the best way to get `MXGB0TC`, i.e. what's after `6922=` and then on the left of the first pipe once its been split on `6922=`

Tried the below for the first part of this, but I guess `B0TC|6970=5|6926=F|6974=P`

```
=RIGHT(A2; SEARCH(6922&"=";A2;1)-1)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Change the `-1` to `+2`

Comment: Hi Fellow Pete, is the length of `MXGB0TC` always going to be 7 chars, and will it always be after `6922=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  Assuming the general format of your search string remains the same, try this:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("6922=",A2)-4),SEARCH("|",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("6922=",A2)-4))-1)
```

Edit: Per your comment, if your desired value is always 7 characters, you can shorten to this:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("6922=",A2)-4),7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find this useful.

Select your range, then use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range

This will open the Power Query Editor. Then you can use Split-columns on pipe and separate to rows to produce this:

[image]

Then you can use split column on delimiter="=" to get this:

[image]

You can filter here or just use Home>Close & Load to put all the data back into the workbook.

Here's my query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"data", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"data", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "data"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"data", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "data", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("=", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"data.1", "data.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"data.1", Int64.Type}, {"data.2", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```